# Parsing simple yaml map file with yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I'm trying my best to read a yaml file with yaml-cpp it is in a simple format:

```
test_key:  1
test_key2: 2
test_key3: 3
test_key4: ['value','another value']
test_key5: true
test_key6: [1,2,3,4,5]
test_key7: [0.0,0.1,0.2]
```

The problem is that when I try to parse it this way it will give me the number of items but it will always tell me that they are undefined. For another test I added a sequence in front of it and then it works like I expected and it returns me the type ( first sequence then a map), but I hope that there is another possibility that I maybe just overlooked.

I'm trying to parse the code with a sample code like this one(also if there is a map and behind it a sequence it does it recursively..):

```
YAML::Node file = YAML::LoadFile("sample.yaml");

for(int idx=0;idx<file.size();idx++)
{
   auto node = file[idx];
   switch(node->Type())
   {
    ...

   }
}
```

As a side note I wrote the yaml file also with yaml cpp. I hope someone can advice me what I missed

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete sample that demonstrates the problem, preferably with the output you're seeing.

Comment: it is the minimal sample actually I can reproduce the problem with exactly that yaml file given above and for the code I just switch the different types and print them and it always shows me an undefined type

Comment: you are querying a yaml map for a key that doesn't exist that's why you get undefined. You should do something like this:for (YAML::Node::iterator mIte = file.begin(); mIte != file.end(); mIte++)
  {

Comment: thank you that did the trick